# Make a link using jQuery

Tags: jquery, url, hyperlink

I have this code, where i am parsing a URL to pass a path to another URL, both within the same domain. I have successfully, parsed it an made a new URL but now I am having trouble turning it into a link. This is what I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var URL = 'https://www.site-name.com/f1'; // MAIN URL

  var otherURL = 'https://www.site-name.com/Manual/module_1_4_2.htm'; // Other URL

  //Create a new link with the url as its href:
  var a = $('<a>', {
    href: otherURL
  });
  var sResult = '<b>Protocol:</b> ' + a.prop('protocol') + '<br/>' + '<b>Host name: </b>' + a.prop('hostname') + '<br/>' + '<b>Path: </b>' + a.prop('pathname') + '<br/>'

  var path = a.prop('pathname'); // pass the path to the MAIN URL 
  var newURL = URL + "?page=" + path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

  // display new URL 
  $('span').html(sResult + "<br><b>New URL: </b>" + newURL);

  // Correctly displays New URL:https://www.site-name.com/f1? page=module_1_4_2.htm

  // How do I turn it into a link ?

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Just wrap the link with <a> tag, <a href=" + newURL + "> ..</a>

Comment: @Yi Zhou something like this `$('#container').html('<a href="'+newURL+'">TEST LINK</a>'); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new '' element, set the url and text of the link, then append it right after `NEW URL:`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var URL = 'https://www.site-name.com/f1'; // MAIN URL

  var otherURL = 'https://www.site-name.com/Manual/module_1_4_2.htm'; // Other URL

  //Create a new link with the url as its href:
  var a = $('<a>', {
    href: otherURL
  });
  var sResult = '<b>Protocol:</b> ' + a.prop('protocol') + '<br/>' + '<b>Host name: </b>' + a.prop('hostname') + '<br/>' + '<b>Path: </b>' + a.prop('pathname') + '<br/>'

  var path = a.prop('pathname'); // pass the path to the MAIN URL 
  var newURL = URL + "?page=" + path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

  // display new URL
  var newLink = $('<a>',{
    href: newURL,
    text: newURL
  })
  $('span').html(sResult + "<br><b>New URL: </b>").append(newLink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way that you created `a`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var URL = 'https://www.site-name.com/f1'; // MAIN URL

  var otherURL = 'https://www.site-name.com/Manual/module_1_4_2.htm'; // Other URL

  //Create a new link with the url as its href:
  var a = $('<a>', {
    href: otherURL
  });
  var sResult = '<b>Protocol:</b> ' + a.prop('protocol') + '<br/>' + '<b>Host name: </b>' + a.prop('hostname') + '<br/>' + '<b>Path: </b>' + a.prop('pathname') + '<br/>'

  var path = a.prop('pathname'); // pass the path to the MAIN URL 
  var newURL = URL + "?page=" + path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

  // display new URL 
  $('span').html(sResult + "<br><b>New URL: </b>" + newURL);

  // Correctly displays New URL:https://www.site-name.com/f1? page=module_1_4_2.htm

  // How do I turn it into a link ?

  var new_a = $('<a>', {
    href: newURL,
    text: 'Click here for new URL'
  });
  $('div').append(new_a);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
<div></div>
```

Comment: if I have an iframe in the main URL page `https://www.site-name.com/f1`, how do I go about passing the path to the iframe. This is my iframe `<iframe style="overflow: hidden;" name="myiframe"id="load" src="https://www.site-name.com/Manual/application.htm"></iframe>`

Comment: Do you mean you want to use this as the `src` of the iframe? `$("#load").attr("src", newURL);`

Comment: yes, I want the iframe to always have /application.htm but if a path exists pass the path like i'm doing in the code I posted, to have the link we just created load in the iframe, therefore I need to pass the path to the iframe as well.